# SQL Server: Sum of childs column (sum only until no negative value left for childs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, common-table-expression

again i have got a small (i hope small) problem.

I have got a parent child hirarchy where one parent can have multiple childs and a child can have again multiple childs and so on.

every parent and child has a amount (value) and a parent can compensate for any missing amount of the childrens.

Here my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL
,ParentID INTEGER
,NAME VARCHAR(20)
,value INTEGER
)
```

Testdata:

`INSERT  INTO #Test
        ( ID, ParentID, NAME, value )
VALUES  ( 1, NULL, 'MainStore', 1 )
,       ( 2, 1, 'Substore1', 3 )
,       ( 3, 1, 'Substore2', 10 )
,       ( 4, 2, 'Sub1Substore1', -1 )
,       ( 5, 2, 'Sub1Substore2', 1 )
,       ( 6, 3, 'Sub2Substore1', 10 )`

To get the parentchild realationship displayed ive tried it with an CTE:

```
;WITH    CTE
      AS ( SELECT   ID
                   ,ParentID
                   ,Name
                   ,Value
                   ,0 AS LEVEL
                   ,CAST('' AS INTEGER) AS ID_Parent
           FROM     #Test
           WHERE    ParentID IS NULL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   child.ID
                   ,child.ParentID
                   ,child.Name
                   ,child.Value
                   ,parent.Level + 1
                   ,parent.ID
           FROM     CTE parent
                    JOIN #Test child ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
         )
```

As you can see Substore1 has 2 childrens (Sub1Substore1 and Sub1Substore2) Substore1 hast a value of 3, Sub1Substore1 -1 and Sub1Substore2 has 1.

Sub1Substore1 is a child of Substore1 and the parent can compensate for missing values of the childs.

My desired output should look like this:

```
ID          ParentID    Name                 Value       LEVEL       ID_Parent   FreeValues
----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        MainStore            1           0           0           1
2           1           Substore1            3           1           1           2
3           1           Substore2            10          1           1           8
4           2           Sub1Substore1        -1          2           2           0
5           2           Sub1Substore2        1           2           2           1
6           3           Sub2Substore1        -2          2           3           0
```

Sadly the SQL Fiddle Website is not working for me at the moment but i will provide this sample later on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: What exactly is column FreeValues? And why doubling of parent id?

Comment: Free values are the values i want to calculate. Sub1Substore2 has value = 1 and no childs it needs to compensate so freeValue = 1, Substore1 has two childs and one of them has value = -1 so it needs to compensate for this. Sbstore1 value = 3 - value for child = FreeValue 2. The double Column for parent Id has no special reason. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Rewrote whole answer due to misunderstandment of the task.

This might be solvable elegantly with common table expression, but because CTE lacks support for multiple recursive references, this task seemed to became way too complex for me to handle.

However, here's a bit less elegant solution that should do the trick for you. Note that I made an assumption that parent's ID is always smaller than it's direct childrens'. This might become an issue if you should be able to change already inserted row's parent "on-the-fly". Anyway, here you go:

```
--Declare temp table.
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL
,ParentID INTEGER
,NAME VARCHAR(20)
,value INTEGER
,FreeValues INTEGER
,NeedFromParent INTEGER
,ChildrenNeed INTEGER
);

--Other variables
DECLARE @ID INTEGER
DECLARE @ParentID INTEGER
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @value INTEGER
DECLARE @FreeValues INTEGER
DECLARE @NeedFromParent INTEGER
DECLARE @ChildrenNeed INTEGER

--Loop with cursor to calculate FreeValues
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, parentId, Name, Value FROM #test 
ORDER BY ID DESC -- NOTE! Assumed that Parent's ID < Child's ID.
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @ParentID, @Name, @value
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @ChildrenNeed = CASE
   WHEN SUM(temp.NeedFromParent) IS NULL THEN 0 
   ELSE SUM(temp.NeedFromParent) END
  FROM @temp temp WHERE temp.ParentID=@ID AND temp.NeedFromParent > 0

  IF @ChildrenNeed IS NULL SET @ChildrenNeed = 0

  IF @Value - @ChildrenNeed < 0 
    SET @NeedFromParent = @Value - @ChildrenNeed
  ELSE
    SET @NeedFromParent = 0

  SET @NeedFromParent = -@NeedFromParent

  IF @NeedFromParent = 0 
    SET @FreeValues = @value - @ChildrenNeed
  ELSE
    SET @FreeValues = 0

  INSERT INTO @Temp 
    VALUES(@ID, @ParentID, @Name, @value, @FreeValues, @NeedFromParent, @ChildrenNeed)
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @ParentID, @Name, @value
END 
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

-- Join with recursively calculated Level.
;WITH CTE
 AS ( SELECT ID ,ParentID,0 AS [Level]
      FROM  #Test WHERE ParentID IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT child.ID,child.ParentID,parent.Level + 1
      FROM CTE parent INNER JOIN #Test child ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
   ) 
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ParentID, t1.Name, t1.Value, cte.[Level], t1.FreeValues 
FROM CTE cte LEFT JOIN @temp t1 ON t1.ID = cte.ID 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks that helps me and yes -2 is correct. Sorry :-) But one small prob is left.. if i add another child for Sub1Substore1 ( 7, 4, 'Sub1Sub1Substore1', -1 ) with value -1 then the parent with ID 2 (Substore1) should compensate for that too. at the moment it works only one level down. i know iam breaking my head over this some time too now :/